# Why does InnoDB use a next-key lock when performing a less-than query with a non-primary index?

Tags: mysql, innodb

kernel: 5.15.133.1-microsoft-standard-WSL2

mysql-server version: 8.0.33-0ubuntu0.22.04.2

transaction isolation level: REPEATABLE-READ

DDL:

```
CREATE TABLE `test` (
  `id` bigint NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `uk` bigint DEFAULT NULL,
  `index` bigint DEFAULT NULL,
  `indexless` bigint DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`) USING BTREE,
  UNIQUE KEY `uk` (`uk`) USING BTREE,
  KEY `index` (`index`) USING BTREE
) ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

data:

```
mysql> select * from test;
+----+------+-------+-----------+
| id | uk   | index | indexless |
+----+------+-------+-----------+
|  1 |    1 |     1 |         1 |
|  5 |    5 |     5 |         5 |
| 10 |   10 |    10 |        10 |
| 15 |   15 |    15 |        15 |
+----+------+-------+-----------+

INSERT INTO `test`.`test`(`id`, `uk`, `index`, `indexless`) VALUES (1, 1, 1, 1);
INSERT INTO `test`.`test`(`id`, `uk`, `index`, `indexless`) VALUES (5, 5, 5, 5);
INSERT INTO `test`.`test`(`id`, `uk`, `index`, `indexless`) VALUES (10, 10, 10, 10);
INSERT INTO `test`.`test`(`id`, `uk`, `index`, `indexless`) VALUES (15, 15, 15, 15);
```

When i execute sql

```
begin; SELECT * FROM test WHERE `index` < 6 FOR SHARE;
```

or

```
begin; SELECT * FROM test WHERE uk < 6 FOR SHARE;
```

i got these locks info:

```
mysql> select LOCK_TYPE, LOCK_MODE, LOCK_STATUS, LOCK_DATA from performance_schema.data_locks;
+-----------+---------------+-------------+-----------+
| LOCK_TYPE | LOCK_MODE     | LOCK_STATUS | LOCK_DATA |
+-----------+---------------+-------------+-----------+
| TABLE     | IS            | GRANTED     | NULL      |
| RECORD    | S             | GRANTED     | 1, 1      |
| RECORD    | S             | GRANTED     | 5, 5      |
| RECORD    | S             | GRANTED     | 10, 10    |
| RECORD    | S,REC_NOT_GAP | GRANTED     | 1         |
| RECORD    | S,REC_NOT_GAP | GRANTED     | 5         |
+-----------+---------------+-------------+-----------+
```

but, primary-key search got these locks:

```
begin; SELECT * FROM test WHERE id < 6 FOR SHARE;

mysql> select LOCK_TYPE, LOCK_MODE, LOCK_STATUS, LOCK_DATA from performance_schema.data_locks;
+-----------+-----------+-------------+-----------+
| LOCK_TYPE | LOCK_MODE | LOCK_STATUS | LOCK_DATA |
+-----------+-----------+-------------+-----------+
| TABLE     | IS        | GRANTED     | NULL      |
| RECORD    | S         | GRANTED     | 1         |
| RECORD    | S         | GRANTED     | 5         |
| RECORD    | S,GAP     | GRANTED     | 10        |
+-----------+-----------+-------------+-----------+
```

range 5-10 locked with gap lock.

Question is:
Why does InnoDB use next-key locks instead of gap locks for the range 5-10 (LOCK_DATA: 10, 10) with a non-primary index?

Comment: From what i remember is that because you are inserting in a low range. whenever your table is getting fuller its different. RDBMS decide on their own in many cases what they do.

Comment: What happens with "7" instead of "6"?

Comment: @RickJames The same applies; non-primary key indexes also use next-key lock.